# Primeng Edit Table running with protractor getting element not found error

Tags: javascript, protractor, primeng

Following is my html code for primeng editable table,

```
<tr>
    <td *ngFor="let fields of header; let i=index;" pEditableColumn>
        <p-cellEditor>
            <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                <input id="edit-col-{{i}}" pInputText type="text"
                    [(ngModel)]="rows[fields.fieldId].data">
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                <div class="scrollable-div">
                    <span>
                        {{rows[fields.fieldId].data}}
                    </span>
            </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-cellEditor>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my protractor code,

```
    selectedElement = element(by.xpath('//tr[@id=\'new-row-1\']'));
    const eachCols = selectedElement.all(by.tagName('td'));

    eachCols.each(async (ele, index) => {

        //click element to view the edit box
        genericAction.clickButton(ele).then(async () => { 

        const inputElement = element(by.id(`edit-col-${index}`));
            await genericAction.setInputField(inputElement,"new data");
        });

    });
```

with the above code click is working fine, but while providing the input, getting the following error to fill the value, **No element found using locator: By(css selector, *[id="edit-col-0"])** I am not sure what I am missing it.

Answer (score 0):

The index is not filled.
As I'm not working with protractor, I can make only assumptions how to fix it but my guess would be this:

```
    $(eachCols).each(async (ele, index) => {

        //click element to view the edit box
        genericAction.clickButton(ele).then(async () => { 

            const inputElement = element(by.id('edit-col-' + index));
            await genericAction.setInputField(inputElement,"new data");
        });

    });
```

And you've **perhaps** to change the according line like this:

```
            await genericAction.setInputField($(inputElement),"new data");
```